# Trying to do post from an Azure function with pem and key

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

We were trying to do a post query from an Azure function net core 3.1. 
We have the format for cURL

```
curl -i -k --cert ${PATH-TO-YOUR-CERT} --key ${PATH-TO-YOUR-KEY} https://example.com/v0/api -X POST -d '{"field1": "data1", "field2": "data2"}'
```

But we don't know how to do this operation from an Azure Function. We don't know how to use pem anf key nor how to get the certs into a function.

Is there a way to put it each cert on b64 into varaibles instead of upload the file?

How could it be the code to post with net core?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40168302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a real production, you can use Azure Key Vault to store your key and retrieve it in your Azure Function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates

In order to retrieve it, you can use Key Vault References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references