# How to configure a client certificate in IIS Server for any outgoing calls that originates FROM a site TO a https application

Tags: iis, certificate

We have deployed a site in IIS server which connects to an external application which expects a client certificate (Client/Server Authentication)

Unfortunately since we don't have control to the source code of the site, we are unable to configure a client certificate to all outgoing calls to the specific application, as part of site's source code

***So we are looking for an option to configure a client certificate in IIS server for all calls that originates FROM an iis site TO an external application***

Comment: You can export certificate on client and [import into IIS](https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm), then choose "https" in add site binding of site.

Comment: Hi Bruce, Thanks for your response. The steps provided in the given link is to bind a certificate for an existing site in IIS. So the added certificate will represent the site.

Comment: What I am looking is, I want to add a client certificate for all outbound calls that originates FROM an iis site TO a specific external URL.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it cannot be configured in IIS. IIS can only configure the certificate of the inbound request, and verify the certificate with the requesting client.

As far as I know, there are two ways to give a station request to add a certificate. One is to [add a custom module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/2tw134k3(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in IIS, which intercepts outbound requests and adds a client certificate so that the request can communicate with external sites.

Another method is to [configure the certificate through code within the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014047/add-client-certificate-to-net-core-httpclient). You need to add a reference to the certificate and set the request.