# In C#, asp.net web api, how do you add a .pem certificate and .key file to a post request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is for C# server side using ASP.NET Web API.
I need to send a Post request that has a certificate .pem file and a .key file. How do I attach them to my Post request?

Comment: To confirm, your web-service is making an outgoing HTTP request of its own?

Comment: Windows/.NET doesn't use the PEM format, it uses the PKCS12 format (aka `.pfx`) - there are plenty of tools for converting certificate formats.

Comment: After you've loaded your `.pfx` into an `X509Certificate2` instance, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014047/add-client-certificate-to-net-core-httpclient