# Dynamically add a client certificate to a HttpClient

Tags: c#, authentication, httpclient, client-certificates

**Problem statement**

What is the best way to dynamically add a client certificate to a `HttpClient` in C#? I have an application that needs to call the same endpoint with different client certificates (We are calling an API on behalf of our clients).

**Scenario:**

We are not able to use *named* `HttpClient`s because our customer base will grow and shrink dynamically. What I had in mind was to create a `HttpClientFactory` so you could do the following. Doing so creates new problems e.g. socket exhaustion.

```cs
var factory = new HttpClientFactory()
var certificate = new X509Certificate2();
HttpClient customerClient = factory.CreateClient(certificate)
```

**Research:**

- https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/932

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add client certificate to .NET Core HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014047/add-client-certificate-to-net-core-httpclient)

Comment: Sadly not. I am aware of how to attach a client certificate to a HttpClient. One solution is just to manually create a new HttpClient per request, but it creates new problems e.g. socket exhaustion.