# Using HttpClient with .NET 6 C#, I'm getting a decryption error when making an http post request

Tags: c#, iis, httpclient, .net-6.0, x509

I have been getting the following exception:

> System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I use a simple post request to send a message using TLS 1.3 and a certificate bound to IIS on Windows Server 2022. This happens when I hit one specific web site that requires the certificate validation.

Any suggestion on how I can troubleshoot this issue? could this be related to `HttpClient` not using the correct certificate, if yes then what steps can I take to run some validation?

Thanks.

Here is the code I use:

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/soap+xml");
            using (var response = await client.PostAsync("host url", content))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                    //Return result 
                    return (result);
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    return ( string.Empty);
                }
            }
```

Comment: "when I hit one specific web site that requires the certificate validation." What sort of certificate validation do you mean, do you mean client certificate, and what does that have to do with IIS and the certificate it is bound to? How do you know TLS 1.3 is specifically at fault? Please show relevant code.

Comment: You need to edit the question to show your code that "send a message using TLS 1.3". And how many certificates do you have at hand? Note that there are client certificates and server certificates, so the type of certificate you used in your code matters a lot.

Comment: There is one server certificate. Not sure if this is related to sending with TLS 1.3, but might be. I need help to figure out what the issue is. It only happens for one web site that requires the specific server certificate, for a different web site api (different host name) the request goes fine. Is there a way I can figure out if httpclient is using the specific server certificate or some other certificate? Also, how is the decryption exception related to the certificate? I ask since I am not sure if it relates. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You seem to be confusing different certificates: the one that ASP.Net and IIS use to serve requests, the one used by any server which is contacted by ASP.Net using `HttpClient`, and the certificate supplied by `HttpClient` to identify itself as a client. These are three different things: which one are you having issues with? As mentioned: **please show relevant code**.

Comment: The web site that my api calls requires a certain certificate when I call it from my API to send it json message. I've setup windows 2022 server with IIS. I installed the certificate that I own on that server. I have deployed my dotnet 6 API that will need to send the Json request to the destination web site. Now, when I use httpclient in my code it throws the exception. This the issue that I have. The code is very simple httpclient postasync with json message as content.

Comment: _"The code is very simple httpclient postasync with json message as content."_ - Then you won't have any difficulties to hit the [edit] link and copy & paste that code into your question (in a fenced code section), which you have been requested to do _twice_ already. Right?

Comment: See code in original post.

Comment: So "a certificate bound to IIS on Windows Server 2022" is for where? The server you are contacting at `"host url"` or the one you are contacting from? Are both servers fully up to date with the latest Windows and .NET updates? which builds are they on?

Comment: I figured out what the issue is. One of your comments indicated to potential use of different certificate by httpclient which was the case. Apparently HttpClient uses its own certificate to send the post request. I had to change the code to add a manual certificate to the HttpClient Handler which got things working. I wish Microsoft documented this a bit more. Anyway thanks @Charlieface for giving me a hint on what to look for! I have also found useful help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014047/add-client-certificate-to-net-core-httpclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue is. One of your comments indicated to potential use of different certificate by httpclient which was the case. Apparently HttpClient uses its own certificate to send the post request. I had to change the code to add a manual certificate to the HttpClient Handler which got things working. I wish Microsoft documented this a bit more. Anyway thanks @Charlieface for giving me a hint on what to look for! I have also found useful help in [Add client certificate to .NET Core HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014047/add-client-certificate-to-net-core-httpclient)